# Problems with the Turtlebot Dashboard Launch

Tags: roslaunch, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I type in rqt -s turtlebot_dashboard to terminal I get the error

WARNING: Package name "swig-wx" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
WARNING: Package name "swig-wx" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
RosPyPluginProvider.discover() could not find ROS master, all rospy-based plugins are disabled
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "turtlebot_dashboard"

What do I do to launch the Dashboard?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57686/problems-with-the-turtlebot-dashboard-launch/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-11**:
You could overlook this warning. I get this warning every time and it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe Groovy by default assumes a TurtleBot is using a Kabuki base with related drivers and sensors.  When using a TurtleBot with the Create base, you'll see errors similar to that in the original post.

For me the key to getting a dashboard up with the Create base is to set the following environment variables on both the robot laptop and the remote workstation:

```
export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect
```

I can then get a working dashboard by running the following on the robot laptop:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

And the following command on my workstation laptop:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) with karma: 153 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-17**:
You are right.